# find all words that begin with @ and that contain all chars except for spaces in regex

Tags: php, regex

The title says it all.

This is what I have:

```
preg_match_all("/@[\w_.]+/",$text_tbh, $matches);
```

but that does not include words with special chars.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\S` which matches any non-white space character.

```
preg_match_all('/@\S+/', $text_tbh, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

What special chars do you whant? Include them in the brackets!

Ie

```
preg_match_all("/@[\w._#?!+]+/",$text_tbh, $matches);
```

Comment: The `g` flag means *global*, not *greedy*, and PHP doesn't use it.  That's what the `preg_match_all` method is for (as opposed to `preg_match`).